# Как получить тип ключа в словаре Dictionary C#?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
IDictionary dict = new Dictionary<..., ...>();
Type keyType = dict.GetType().GetKeyType(); (как?)
```

Comment: `Type type = dict.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];`

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dictionary<int, string> dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
Type[] argumentsTypes = dictionary.GetType().GetGenericArguments();
Type keyType = argumentsTypes[0]; // Тип ключа
Type valueType = argumentsTypes[1]; // Тип значения
```